# Unable to parse the json array from api response angular

Tags: angular

I have data json data as below
this.products

```
atttributes: Array(1)
0: { Front Camera: "8"
RAM: "16"
Rear Camera: "13"
id: 16
pictureUrl: "https://localhost:5001/images/products/realme.png"
price: 36
prodDescription: "Mobile Ph1"
prodName: "Apple"
productCategory: "Mobile"}
```

I am unable to get the value for atttributes field.
I have used json pipe in angular in HTML
`<span class="mb-2">{{product.atttributes | json}}</span>`
but is displaying result as below 
`[ { "RAM": "16", "Front Camera": "8", "Rear Camera": "13" } ]`

[Response Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwBnR.png)

[HTML binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvO2c.png)

Comment: hi there, you might want to share some snippets of the code, not only the data you are observing and here you can find some guidance as to how to ask better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: attributes is an array, the result is correct

Comment: 0:
atttributes: Array(1)
0:
Front Camera: "8"
RAM: "16"
Rear Camera: "13"

id: 16
pictureUrl: "https://localhost:5001/images/products/realme.png"
price: 36
prodDescription: "Mobile Ph1"
prodName: "Apple"
productCategory: "Mobile"

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I want to display like this RAM:16 Front Camer:8 Rear Camera:13

Comment: if attributes is expected to only have 1 value of array then {{ product.attributes[0] | json }} or change the return to object rather than array otherwise you have to loop it and get its attributes

Comment: I have used json pipe but data is showing as below { "RAM": "16", "Front Camera": "8", "Rear Camera": "13" }

Answer (score 0):

`json` pipe

> Converts a value into its JSON-format representation. Useful for debugging. [source](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)

you cant use it to get its properties, if you want to get the property of an object / json do it like this

```html
// for Mobile
<ng-container *ngIf="product.productCategory == 'Mobile' ">
    <span> RAM : {{ product.attributes[0]?.RAM }} </span>
    <span> // more specs ...
</ng-container>

// for Cars
<ng-container *ngIf="product.productCategory == 'Car' ">
    // whatever property your Car model has, in this example, its name
    <span> Car : {{ product.attributes[0]?.name }} </span> 
</ng-container>
```

your attributes object keys contain spaces, like "Front Camera" : 8 , change it to "frontCamera" : 8 instead

if you can't change it then try something like this if it works, I haven't tried it.

```html
<span> RAM : {{ product.attributes[0]?.['Front Camera'] }} </span>
```

Note: `?` is called safe navigation operator, so that it wont cause an exception when .RAM or ['Front Camera'] does not exist

If your `product.attributes[0]` is dynamic then display different views depending on your `productCategory`

Comment: thank  you it is partially working but not getting desire out put it not working for dynamic when i am putting <span> RAM : {{ product.attributes[0]?.RAM }} </span> then RAM is coming for mobile and car  type product.

Comment: I didn't know your attributes data is dynamic, i'll edit my answer